# Purging CloudFlare cache with Slackbot

Tags: caching, devops, slack, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I want to understand is there any way to purge cache from Cloudflare using a slack bot? I already have a bot. I read about an online article that says this can be done using cloudflare workers. I'd like to know if there is any better way than this? Or is this is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need cloudflare workers, you just need to make an [API call](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-Purging-cached-resources-from-Cloudflare#77FAONPoEzPXUhsRIjFPmW) which can likely be done from the slackbot itself.